# Running Javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm creating a word press theme , this includes a responsive jquery menu.

However, for some reason, I can't get the menu to work. In my functions.PHP file I have included the script below. Please may someone help with advice and a code snippet, i'm trying to:

1) Call Jquery

2) Run the script slimmenu.js script

```
<?php

function menu_function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() .   '/js/jquery.slimmenu.js', array( 'jquery'));
    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','menu_function');

?>
```

Many thanks, 
P

Answer (score 0):

You have not enqueued jquery which is a dependancy for the script you've enqueued. Also consider naming your file something a bit more unique to avoid conflicts. try...

```
function menu_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slimMenu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.slimmenu.js', 'jquery' );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','menu_scripts');
```

Comment: No need to explicitly enqueue jQuery as WordPress has a copy of jQuery already registered. Stating a registered script as a dependency of another script enqueues it. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery

Answer (score -2):

Better add the script in footer.php before :

```
 <?php
    wp_footer();
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() .   '/js/jquery.slimmenu.js', 'jquery', true);
?>
```